# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"string" | "union" | "of"'

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAygKgggSlAXGALgTwA4FMDOYBmATgPYC2YAAigIYB2ONAxgNbCFbWMoC0NARgBssYAMIwAcuIDyUMACEAomBgBZFQvEARBZrAhgAKAMBLWiiyF8nYSOICArqVoAxYwPOEwAbwNgwxgBNkBkJTAHMAbl8wADdqByxke1pmWmIAd1oogF8jdGwwAFUMAOoPAB4oAD4wAF4wWQAfMAAKFrsghoBKOpqoLqj84SlaEQALOjCsZ1pKmvqW+xKyiylCADV4+0Si5YrqntqamOJAqIMh0TtHFzcPHAgaczqrhydXdwsAbQBdc9MPFZGMIPvcoNRBFhHitvNFGNd3ncLDhkLY3rdPoQHk8sFE-GEBMQ+PFQRZkHQ0DkjACLEDhODIdDnlgAB7mWgBPCkrEMoRM4ReMC5AygMAaTTIIZ4IhkSg0ehMVjsTg8fhCUQSaSyRTKNTinR6QwGVkYYiEFD+My06xgTRlai8rBom7c7ErSp2mg1VnszmvF1Izw+PyBZAKNmEFXlZhYNDEfANT3UAA0YBC4SqeNiWx26dokQMwsu3P5LyTjudiMxbvM5TgWHhhAC5QA5MljMRaC2wM0W-Hu7282EW6mh1VM3lMMIIFgUJWMfcXiNxpNprNHfyvi34ejXS2fhODPCFWnZ-PXchlxN82vyiWcb95q1DjUvNl-lbLDaAAokDB4YNTznBEF2RZAZ2A3dAxwKkj07BgwAwP8UTAX9iH-F5AJwM8QNdQsjCAA)

I am setting up some types with generics with work alongside `@tanstack/table`, this is my current code.

```
import { type ColumnFilter, type OnChangeFn, type TableState } from '@tanstack/react-table';

export interface DataTableColumnFiltersState<TData> extends ColumnFilter {
  id: Extract<keyof TData, string>;
  value: string;
}

type FilterState = DataTableColumnFiltersState<Record<'union' | 'of' | 'string', string>>;

type SetColumnFilters = OnChangeFn<TableState['columnFilters']>;

const setColumnFilters: OnChangeFn<FilterState[]> = () => {};

interface Props {
  setColumnFilters: SetColumnFilters;
}

const props: Props = {
  setColumnFilters
}
```

I am getting a type error on

```
const props: Props = {
  setColumnFilters
}
```

The full type error is

```
Type 'OnChangeFn<FilterState[]>' is not assignable to type 'SetColumnFilters'.
  Types of parameters 'updaterOrValue' and 'updaterOrValue' are incompatible.
    Type 'Updater<ColumnFiltersState>' is not assignable to type 'Updater<FilterState[]>'.
      Type 'ColumnFiltersState' is not assignable to type 'Updater<FilterState[]>'.
        Type 'ColumnFilter[]' is not assignable to type 'FilterState[]'.
          Type 'ColumnFilter' is not assignable to type 'FilterState'.
            Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"string" | "union" | "of"'.
```

I am just confused by the last line of the error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"string" | "union" | "of"'.`

Doesn't `'"string" | "union" | "of"'` imply a `string` type?

Is there any solution to this other than doing

```
const props: Props = {
  setColumnFilters: setColumnFilters as SetColumnFilters
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please see playground link below.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAygKgggSlAXGALgTwA4FMDOYBmATgPYC2YAAigIYB2ONAxgNbCFbWMoC0NARgBssYAMIwAcuIDyUMACEAomBgBZFQvEARBZrAhgAKAMBLWiiyF8nYSOICArqVoAxYwPOEwAbwNgwxgBNkBkJTAHMAbl8wADdqByxke1pmWmIAd1oogF8jdGwwAFUMAOoPAB4oAD4wAF4wWQAfMAAKFrsghoBKOpqoLqj84SlaEQALOjCsZ1pKmvqW+xKyiylCADV4+0Si5YrqntqamOJAqIMh0TtHFzcPHAgaczqrhydXdwsAbQBdc9MPFZGMIPvcoNRBFhHitvNFGNd3ncLDhkLY3rdPoQHk8sFE-GEBMQ+PFQRZkHQ0DkjACLEDhODIdDnlgAB7mWgBPCkrEMoRM4ReMC5AygMAaTTIIZ4IhkSg0ehMVjsTg8fhCUQSaSyRTKNTinR6QwGVkYYiEFD+My06xgTRlai8rBom7c7ErSp2mg1VnszmvF1Izw+PyBZAKNmEFXlZhYNDEfANT3UAA0YBC4SqeNiWx26dokQMwsu3P5LyTjudiMxbvM5TgWHhhAC5QA5MljMRaC2wM0W-Hu7282EW6mh1VM3lMMIIFgUJWMfcXiNxpNprNHfyvi34ejXS2fhODPCFWnZ-PXchlxN82vyiWcb95q1DjUvNl-lbLDaAAokDB4YNTznBEF2RZAZ2A3dAxwKkj07BgwAwP8UTAX9iH-F5AJwM8QNdQsjCAA)

Comment: "Doesn't `"✂"` imply a `string` type?"  Yes, but not the other way around, which is what it needs to be.  Otherwise you can get a runtime error when `Props` blithely accepts any string `id` in its `setColumnFilters` and the implementation can't handle arbitrary strings.  You probably want `Props` to be generic.  Both the problem and the fix are shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/weLBaW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: All squares are rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares. So you cannot assign a rectangle to something expecting a square. In this stupid example rectangles are `string` and squares are `'a' | 'b'`. If `string` was assignable to `'a' | 'b'`, then you could do this `const input: string = prompt(); const ab: 'a' | 'b' = input`, which would be bad. `string` means any string, `'a' | 'b'` means one of two specific strings.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, that does work. Unfortunately, I have another issue in the same vein, but I cannot seem to recreate it within Typescript Playground to showcase. But thanks, again.

Comment: No don't worry, your answer resolves this issue, the other issue is somewhat separate, it just uses the `DataTableColumnFiltersState` interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"string" | "union" | "of"'.
```

is correct, because `string` is *wider* than any string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) or [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such types.  You can't make this assignment safely:

```
declare const s: string; 
const u: "string" | "union" | "of" = s; // error!
```

After all, `s` could turn out to be any string whatsoever, like `"oops"`, and then you've apparently assigned the value `"oops"` to a variable that expects either `"string"`, `"union"`, or `"of"`.  That's why `string` is not *assignable to* a union of string literals.

The *reverse* assignment wouldn't be a problem, and is probably what confused you. A union of string literals is definitely assignable to `string`, and the following assignment is fine:

```
declare const u: "string" | "union" | "of";
const s: string = u; // okay
```

But that's not what's happening in your example code.

---

The reason you're getting that error is because `SetColumnFilters` has to ultimately accept things whose `id` property is any `string`.  If you try to narrow the `id` property of the things it accepts, you have to *widen* the type of `SetColumnFilters`, not narrow it.  This is because function calls reverse the direction of assignment, and thus reverse the direction of assignability.  If I ask for a `string`, I will be happy with `"of"`.  But if I ask for a function that *accepts* `string`, I will be unhappy with a function that only accepts `"of"`.

(A dog named "Fluffy" is a perfectly reasonable pet, but a veterinarian who only tends to dogs named "Fluffy" would be a completely unreasonable veterinarian, and his protests of "Isn't a dog named 'Fluffy' a pet?" wouldn't change that.)

This direction reversal is known as *contravariance* as it contra-varies, or varies in the opposite way.  See [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for more information.

---

As a demonstration: your `setColumnFilters` expects to ultimately receive things whose `id` property is one of the three strings `"union"`, `"of"`, or `"string"`.  So it should be safe for it to use that `id` to look up a value in some object with those keys:

```
const val = { union: 0, of: 1, string: 2 }
const setColumnFilters: OnChangeFn<FilterState[]> =
  (x) => {
    if (typeof x !== "function")
      x.map(e => val[e.id].toFixed(2))
  };
```

Let's imagine that

```
const props: Props = { setColumnFilters }
```

compiles with no error.  Now since `Props` is defined in terms of `SetColumnFilters`, which is defined where that `id` type is just `string`, the following use of `props` is also considered safe by the compiler:

```
props.setColumnFilters([
  { id: "oops", value: "" }
]);
```

If you actually run that, you'll get a runtime error like `TypeError: val[e.id] is undefined`.  Clearly something bad happened.  But the implementation of `setColumnFilters` adheres perfectly to its contract, and so does the call to `props.setColumnFilters`.  The bad thing was in the compiler allowing you to assign `{ setColumnFilters }` to `Props`.  There should be an error there warning you about this possibility.

And there is indeed such an error!  If you want that to compile with no error you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) as you mention, but that lack of type safety would be your responsibility at that point.

---

If you want to "fix" this without losing type safety then you'll probably need to make your types [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) so that they can mention the specific subtype of `ColumnFilter` they expect.  Maybe like this:

```
type SetColumnFilters<T extends TableState['columnFilters']> =
  OnChangeFn<T>;
interface Props<T extends TableState['columnFilters']> {
  setColumnFilters: SetColumnFilters<T>;
}
```

Now `props` would be of type `Props<FilterState[]>`, which compiles with no error:

```
const props: Props<FilterState[]> = { setColumnFilters } // okay
```

And now the above scenario would give you in error in the *call* to `props.setColumnFilters()`, which is probably where you want such an error to be:

```
props.setColumnFilters([
  { id: "oops", value: "" } // error!
]);
// Type '"oops"' is not assignable to type '"string" | "union" | "of"'.
```

This prompts you to fix the issue by changing `id` from `"oops"` to one of the three supported strings:

```
props.setColumnFilters([
  { id: "union", value: "" }
]); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAygKgggSlAXGALgTwA4FMDOYBmATgPYC2YAAigIYB2ONAxgNbCFbWMoC0NARgBssYAMIwAcuIDyUMACEAomBgBZNWoXiAIgq1gQwAFCGAlrRRZC+TsJHEBAV1K0AYiYEXCYAN6GwYEwATZAZCMwBzAG4-MAA3akcsZAdaZlpiAHdaaIBfY3RsMABVDEDqTwAeKAA+MABeMFkAHzAAClb7YMaASnraqG7oguEpWhEACzpwrBdaKtqG1odS8sspQgA1BIck4pXKmt662tjiIOjDYdF7J1d3TxwIGgt668dnNw9LAG0AXQuzJ5rIxhJ8HlBqIIsE9Vj4Yowbh97pYcMg7O87l9CI9nlhov5wgJiHwEmDLMg6GhcsZAZZgcIIVCYS8sAAPCy0QJ4MnYxlCZnCbxgPKGUBgTRaZDDPBEMiUGj0JisdicHj8ISiCTSWSKZTqfUGw3qCW6fRGQy0aikXAYGxgLRYUjEOH+S3WnC2kH2x3EACMLv8YARirAqNDKDCtHCrwARKyY2AANRgGNoGP4wPBhhgBzIGOhCIJloxlImYi0Isp4j4BMNHCRMDAYBgSwkQgAQhieVdVptdodToATAH-FmUDm8wWo5WS7QyxWwMXq7WwCpyuMAHSEOiBMitXoVMAABg3AFYwAB+FOl8sJvPLmKj8vZsNT6MNBwNptgYjMahoLtDBFC1ew9O0AAUSChchfH8WkrH7cpqD5LB0VuHkcVWKotCQ2o2Q5Lk3nQ5EvFgwMgmQBR2W3LgKmYLA0GrRocJoAAacNI3CaoM38eJEhCCMIgzEV-CuHkBVeFjkMhIQ0KRLFMIsCo4CwBFCECCoAHIb1oTTFzATTqz0lpNLfTT2LfapuOMGIrggLAUDkzEHleUYJimGY5hQgVvk0hEMQwzTfms+Fn3HPjXiFHTkCPdjq2QX0LMEqNkGHbsgzC0MHKcjDkDcyYo08ipxNxP4FkfNpWSOWoyMDAJ8DaYYmNZMB2zqBoY3wFIuHnGNugqurWQ3UhqAwVphGOOIEm+LANyCX4NxQYg3FZLBAlaQdun6uqcguGJ4PpMBIOIDA8FqrLHMRZyUWQezLoCkj60A0KQwwEhTuQY7Tsii6cse4VjH8N6TpwDccGyq6MNab4KqFCiqxBmN2L4nY8wTdLfkGYwRTdPsvRWuF9vMOlEJoFC-oUgVsNwlt2SwTk8ApzwRwCLoqIjVU6IYpioCkpLOOsuqUd2N9hMB1BMFBEiJIaKTychx6qZUtSNO0udy2MgyjP00zkvCcyOIiKyLifEMIoaKL1doGK4vwBL+YiVKAfFuyIYehSqlpgi8G80q-IVhSgvKur8o82Z5gzA6IPenBPfw+nCN91ZfP84jA+ClnwfutOHlut2c5RCPntNl98-k3OwFDwrw5K5OM7qCrWiqvofHqxrJea1r2pTLraB629ej475WW+I8FvmxblpMVb1s24U9pL8dgY+o6Y+K6XSvr1us6ZlFnaBmOwbL67sWh2HWfvRHke2XYY3Rxtm1bYgOxiTGM2-KBJYMmNiERvSTDwOkcc1AcA4BMOES0UJUDOiuJpfMesZw6RnMuTSG5xbL1BjvAODwz51Thl0WcvVr78RTOjV+gwH4-j-ABICQA)